# https request on Service fabric returns a "Can’t connect securely to this page"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, ssl, https, azure-service-fabric

I have an Asp.net MVC application that i have containerized in docker and deployed on Service fabric. The application works perfectly with **HTTP** but when trying to enable **HTTPS** the service responds with a **Can’t connect securely to this page**
There is a wildcard certificate that has been installed on the fabric cluster.
 The DockerFile looks like

```
FROM  mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1803
ARG source
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source} . 
RUN Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server; `
    Add-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET; `
    Add-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45; 
HEALTHCHECK   --retries=5  --interval=100s --start-period=10s   CMD curl --fail http://localhost || exit 1 
EXPOSE 80
```

The service manifest has the following endpoint

```
<Resources>
<Endpoints>
  <!-- This endpoint is used by the communication listener to obtain the port on which to 
       listen. Please note that if your service is partitioned, this port is shared with 
       replicas of different partitions that are placed in your code. -->
  <Endpoint Name="BookingApiServiceTypeEndpoint"  UriScheme="https" Protocol="https" Type="Input" Port="61650" />
</Endpoints></Resources>
```

The application manifest has the following ServiceManifestImport

```
<ServiceManifestImport>
<ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="BookingApiServicePkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
<ConfigOverrides />
<Policies>
  <ContainerHostPolicies CodePackageRef="Code" AutoRemove="false" UseDefaultRepositoryCredentials="false" ContainersRetentionCount="2"  RunInteractive="true">
     <PortBinding ContainerPort="80" EndpointRef="BookingApiServiceTypeEndpoint"  />        
    <HealthConfig IncludeDockerHealthStatusInSystemHealthReport="true" RestartContainerOnUnhealthyDockerHealthStatus="false"/>
   </ContainerHostPolicies>
  <EndpointBindingPolicy EndpointRef="BookingApiServiceTypeEndpoint" CertificateRef="HttpsCert" />
</Policies></ServiceManifestImport>
```

With the service tag as

```
 <Service Name="BookingApiService" ServiceDnsName="bookingapi.dutchhub.com" ServicePackageActivationMode="ExclusiveProcess">
  <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="BookingApiServiceType" InstanceCount="1">
    <SingletonPartition />
  </StatelessService></Service>
```

and the Certificates tag as

```
 <Certificates>
<EndpointCertificate X509FindValue="[HttpsCertThumbprint]" Name="HttpsCert"/> </Certificates>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Change your `PortBinding` to target port 443
- Configure IIS to use port 443 and a valid certificate
- Change your dockerfile to expose port 443
- Open port 443 on the load balancer

more info in [this walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-dotnet-app-enable-https-endpoint)

Comment: do u mean IIS in the container ?

Comment: so the container and the fabric cluster both need the certificate installed?

Comment: I believe only the container needs it, unless you also run services without using containers.